# Partially refresh html contents on set interval with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, reload

I have a HTML page like this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function reload(){
    $( "#id_1" ).load(window.location.href + " #id_1" );
    $( "#id_2" ).load(window.location.href + " #id_2" );
    }
}
</script></head>
<body>
<span id="id_1">Something</span>
<div id="id_2" >Something</div>
</body>
```

I want to execute `reload()` every 10 seconds without affecting the overall performance of the page. There are a lot of buttons in the DOM that have `onClick()` bindings, and it is very important that their performance is not affected.

I tried to use `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`, but the page stops working until the defined period has passed. I also looked into a web worker, but I couldn't find a way to do that. As far as I know, a web worker doesn't have access to the DOM.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You are loading parts of a page from within the loaded page... Typically one would make requests to separate URLs. It's also unclear how loading the word "Something" would affect performance.

Comment: What is the goal of all this?  I don't think this approach is going to achieve your desired results.  Can you give us more information about what you hope to achieve so we can better help you?

Answer (score -1):

I did this with ajax. You can define a function to fetch content to the divs that you need to reload. Say function a, then attach a setinterval function to function a.

It should work Im sure